# How to create a dummy file with Perl?

Tags: performance, perl, file

How would I create a dummy file with Perl? I need to create a few million files (approx. 5KB - 1MB each), so it is very important to do it as fast as possible. So, what would be the fastest way to create a dummy file with Perl?

Comment: [Benchmark](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Benchmark) it?

Comment: Doing it "as fast as possible" might mean running parallel jobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "OK, this works, but how to define dummy file with exact size, say 2KB ?" – user1039509

This should work:

```
open FH, '>', 'dummy.file' and print FH "X" x 2048 and close FH or die $!;
```

If you don't care what the files contain, using `seek` might be slightly faster yet:

```
open FH, '>', 'dummy.file' and seek FH, 2047, 0 and print FH "\0"
    and close FH or die $!;
```

Comment: Wow, is that ever hard to read!  Even if you won’t use normal punctuation, can't you please use parentheses for your function calls?

Answer (score 2):

```
my $DUMMY;

open $DUMMY, '>', 'dummy.file' and close $DUMMY;
```

Comment: OK, this works, but how to define dummy file with exact size, say 2KB ?